# Java - Deployment Error - Unexpected content of type 'element start' named '{urn:jboss:module:1.1}module'

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jboss, jsf-2.2

I was trying to add `jsf2.2` into `JBoss 7.0 server` following **[this article's](http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jsf/installing-jsf-22-on-jboss-as-7)** 2nd option. I created folder with name `2.2` within `/modules/javax/faces/api/` and `modules\com\sun\jsf-impl` and added **jsf-api-2.2.14.jar** and **jsf-impl-2.2.14.jar** respectively.

The `module.xml` file within `/modules/javax/faces/api/2.2` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="javax.faces.api" slot="2.2">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.el.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.jstl.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="2.2"/>
    </dependencies>

    <resources>
       <resource-root path="jsf-api-2.2.14.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

and `module.xml` file within `/modules/com/sunjsf-impl/2.2` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="2.2">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="2.2"/>
        <module name="javaee.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.jstl.api"/>
        <module name="org.apache.xerces" services="import"/>
        <module name="org.apache.xalan" services="import"/>
    </dependencies>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jsf-impl-2.2.14.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

and `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` looks like below in both **Project** and and **JBoss Server**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <exclusions>
     <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
     <module name="javax.faces.api" />
     <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" />
    </exclusions>
 <dependencies>
     <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="2.2"/>
     <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="2.2"/>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

After all these set up done, when I run the project, I get below **error** in **modules\javax\faces\api\2.2\module.xml**

> **Unexpected content of type 'element start' named
>   '{urn:jboss:module:1.1}module'**

But I don't know what's wrong with that line in file mentioned above. Everything seems valid there. Here is the complete `StackTrace`

```
at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:67) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from D:\Eclipse\jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final\jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final\modules\javax\faces\api\2.2\module.xml
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:249)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:200)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.parseModuleInfoFile(LocalModuleLoader.java:147)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.findModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:124)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:245)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:194)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.preloadModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:97)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadExportedModule(ModuleLoader.java:205)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:218)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ServiceModuleLoader.preloadModule(ServiceModuleLoader.java:161) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:176)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.linkImports(Module.java:1041)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relink(Module.java:1153)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.relink(ModuleLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ServiceModuleLoader.relinkModule(ServiceModuleLoader.java:204) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:64) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[25,72]
Message: Unexpected content of type 'element start' named '{urn:jboss:module:1.1}module'
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.unexpectedContent(ModuleXmlParser.java:312)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:503)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:244)
    ... 20 more
```

Could someone help me out through this?

Answer (score 1):

According to this link

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/171833

a similar problem (but that time caused by the file jboss-deployment-structure.xml ) was solved by removing the namespace attribute from the  element.

Now that your error message is actually the same, why don't you experiment by changing the namespace of (one of) your  elements from

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1"
```

maybe to

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0"
```

Or just try to completely remove the namespace attribute from the  element?

Comment: Didn't help much though, but +1 for your time and effort.. :)